# Is there an expand.grid like function with matrix output

Tags: r

Just curious if there is anything out there - an `expand.grid` like function which would return a matrix rather than a data frame?

Expected output (but not the expected *way to get there*)

```r
as.matrix(expand.grid(1:4,1:4))
#>       Var1 Var2
#>  [1,]    1    1
#>  [2,]    2    1
#>  [3,]    3    1
#>  [4,]    4    1
#>  [5,]    1    2
#>  [6,]    2    2
#>  [7,]    3    2
#>  [8,]    4    2
#>  [9,]    1    3
#> [10,]    2    3
#> [11,]    3    3
#> [12,]    4    3
#> [13,]    1    4
#> [14,]    2    4
#> [15,]    3    4
#> [16,]    4    4
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `crossing` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
as.matrix(crossing(v1 = 1:4, v2= 1:4, v3 = 1:3))
```

---

If we need to directly create a matrix, use

```
cbind(rep(1:4, each = 4), rep(1:4, 4))
```

Comment: Thanks many times. This also goes via a detour, first creating a tibble... But probably already faster than the expand.grid version

Comment: The `CJ` also goes through the same rroute, i.e data.table -> matrix

Comment: @Tjebo I guess you can use `rep`, with `cbind` to directly creeate a matrix

Comment: very interesting. this works only when the vectors are the same (which they are in my case). Great idea.

Comment: @Tjebo No actually, `v1 <- 1:6; v2 = 3:4; cbind(rep(v1, each = length(v2)), rep(v2, length(v1)))`

Comment: sorry to have taken so long - forgot I haven't accepted the answer. Chose yours because it's the closest to what I was asking. Iancampbell's answer is probably more useful for my purpose though, as it does indeed bring the fastest code

Answer (score 4):

If you'd like to do it faster, you could use `data.table`'s `CJ` function and `data.table::as.matrix`.

```
library(data.table)
system.time(matrix <- as.matrix(CJ(1:10000,1:10000)))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.215   0.486   1.709 
system.time(rep.matrix <- cbind(rep(1:10000,each=10000),rep(1:10000,times=10000)))
   user  system elapsed 
  3.193   0.406   3.625 
system.time(matrix <- as.matrix(expand.grid(1:10000,1:10000)))
   user  system elapsed 
  3.506   0.880   4.405
```

Comment: cheers that's something I was looking for :) - although it also creates an intermediate.

Answer (score 1):

Now there is.

```
expand.grid.mat <- function(...) as.matrix(expand.grid(...))

m <- expand.grid.mat(1:4, 1:4, 1:3)
class(m)
# [1] "matrix"
```

Comment: Thanks many times! Unfortunately, that's not really different. I wondered about something without conversion to data frame first.